# Add List of Macros from PERSONAL.XLSB to Right Click Shortcut Menu on application startup

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a sub menu to the right click shortcut menu that contains a list of commonly used macros. I want this to happen when any workbook is opened.

I have tried using the application.WorkbookOpen event (which I believe fires when ANY workbook opens?).

```
Private WithEvents app As Application
Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
Dim Menu As Object
Set Menu = Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell).MenuItems.AddMenu("Macors", 1)


With Menu.MenuItems
    .Add "MacroName", "MacroName", , 1, , ""

End With

 Set MyMenu = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set app = Application
End Sub
```

However, it doesn't seem to fire on start up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what module did you put this code?

Comment: Add the workbook open event to your PERSONAL workbook as it opens when you start Excel up. No need for the `WithEvents` part.

Comment: @Sam The code was origianally in a class module within my personal workbook.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook That is the way I tried it at first, I figured that it was not firing because PERSONAL was not firing the event.